# windows causing breaking point

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic

I am writing a program for a class assignment on learning about pointers and memory management. Allocating memory for student and courses is necessary with the `new` operator in this assignment and the program seems to run properly but after it prints everything the program crashes and it says that that it has triggered a break point. Any help would be appreciated.

The error is located here but I'm not sure what it means
 `/* verify block type */
            _ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct Student //Structs
    {
        string firstName, lastName, aNumber;
        double GPA;
    };
struct Course
    {
        int courseNumber, creditHours;
        string courseName;
        char grade;
    };

Student* readStudent();                                    // Function Prototypes
Course* readCourseArray(int&);
void computeGPA(Student *student, Course *courseArray, int coursesTaken);
void printSummary(Student *studentPTR, Course *courseArray, int courses);
int main()                                                //Main
{
    int courses = 0;
    Student *studentPTR = readStudent();
    Course *coursePTR = readCourseArray(courses);
    computeGPA(studentPTR, coursePTR, courses);
    printSummary(studentPTR, coursePTR, courses);


    delete studentPTR;
    delete coursePTR;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

Student* readStudent()                                       // Read Student
{
    Student* student = new Student;
    cout<<"\nEnter students first name\n";
    cin>>student->firstName;
    cout<<"\nEnter students last name\n";
    cin>>student->lastName;
    cout<<"\nEnter students A-Number\n";
    cin>>student->aNumber;


    return student;
}

Course* readCourseArray(int &courses)                           //Read Courses
{
    cout<<"\nHow many courses is the student taking?\n";
    cin>>courses;
    const int *sizePTR = &courses;
    Course *coursePTR = new Course[*sizePTR]; 

    for(int count = 0; count < *sizePTR; count++)  //Enter course information
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter student "<<count+1<<"'s course name\n";
        cin>>coursePTR[count].courseName;
        cout<<"\nEnter student "<<count+1<<"'s course number\n";
        cin>>coursePTR[count].courseNumber;
        cout<<"\nEnter student "<<count+1<<"'s credit hours\n";
        cin>>coursePTR[count].creditHours;
        cout<<"\nEnter student "<<count+1<<"'s grade\n";
        cin>>coursePTR[count].grade;
    } 


    return coursePTR;
}


void computeGPA(Student *studentPTR, Course *courseArray, int coursesTaken)             // Compute GPA
{
    double total = 0, hours = 0;
    for(int count = 0; count < coursesTaken; count++)
    {
        hours += courseArray[count].creditHours;
        if (courseArray[count].grade == 'A')
            total+=4;
        else if (courseArray[count].grade == 'B')
            total+=3;
        else if (courseArray[count].grade == 'C')
            total+=2;
        else if (courseArray[count].grade == 'D')
            total+=1;
        else if (courseArray[count].grade == 'F')
            total+=0;
    }
    studentPTR->GPA = (total / hours);
}


void printSummary(Student *studentPTR, Course *courseArray, int courses)
{
    cout<<"\nReport\n";
    cout<<"\nNumber   Name                    Hours  Letter Grade  Point Grade";  
    cout<<"\n------   ----                    -----  ------------  -----------\n";
    for(int count = 0; count < courses; count++)
         cout<<setw(3)<<courseArray[count].courseNumber<<"   "<<courseArray[count].courseName<<setw(20)<<"   "<<courseArray[count].creditHours<<setw(5)<<"  "<<courseArray[count].grade<<endl;

    cout<<"\nStudent :"<<studentPTR->firstName<<" "<<studentPTR->lastName;
    cout<<"\nA-Number :"<<studentPTR->aNumber;
    cout<<"\nOverall GPA :"<<studentPTR->GPA;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're allocating courses with operator new[] (which is for arrays), but freeing it with operator delete, instead of operator delete[].

You should deallocate it like that:

```
delete[] coursePTR;
```

I also don't understand why you use the `sizePTR` pointer instead of directly using `courses`.

BTW, just so you'd know, this is not a 'find my bug' site. You have a code review site for that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
delete coursePTR;
```

to

```
delete [] coursePTR;
```

new always needs to be used with delete, and new [] with delete [], otherwise bad things happen.